# What is the probability to find a word w in a random text t with at most a Levenshtein distance of n?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to know if there is a way to express or approach the probability to find a random word `w` (size `lw`) in a random text `t` (size `lt`), using approximate search tools like `tre-agrep` with a maximum Levenshtein distance of `n`. Let's say the size of my alphabet `a` is `la`.

For small `lw` and `lt`, i can get an approximation with a simple and violent algorithm taking a random word `w`, generating every possible texts of length `lt` and counting the number of texts where `w` is found with a distance of `n` or less.

With `la`=4 and `lt`=20, i already have more than 1E12 possible texts.

Does anyone know if some work has already be done about this question or anything close enough to be useful ?